# Install Certman in coldfusion 2016

Tags: coldfusion

Can we install CF-CertMan in Coldfusion 2016 and Coldfusion 2018 CF Admin?

https://github.com/cfmaniac/CF-CertMan

Comment: Why not give it a try and then ask specific questions if it doesn't;t work?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have test servers. I was hoping somebody tried it out and worked.

Comment: https://www.ortussolutions.com/products/commandbox :-)

Comment: You should raise an issue on that repo and ask the code maintainer.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianJ.Moreno I asked the code maintainer.

Comment: You could download Dev versions of each and install them to try it out. Or, you can use CommandBox (as @Ageax noted) to spin up instances of each and try it out.

Comment: I've tried the commndbox> start cfengine=adobe@2018 but getting forbidden in http://127.0.0.1:59105/ I will download a CF2018 and try it out.

Comment: CF-Certman works on CF 2018. I installed the CF10.

Comment: @Vlad - If you were able to confirm it works with one or more of the versions in question, go ahead and post your findings as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I installed both CF2016 and CF2018 on the same machine.  Downloaded the Coldfusion installers in CFMLREPO.com [enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0Bwmlt4TArPS5WDNkZXFCSE1RSkE) The CF10 folder of Certman both works in ColdFusion 2016 and ColdFusion 2018.

Answer (score 0):

I recently added this to cf2023. It does work for viewing certs, but the add does not work.